# Unhide the Ignored Tags Hider

Tags: script, tags

### Screenshot

[image: hide ignored tags]

### About

This is a simple Greasemonkey script which unhides the checkbox which allows you to hide questions with ignored tags.  It allows you to quickly toggle this setting at your leisure without having to navigate to the settings page.  Apparently it has been sitting there the whole time only it was hidden.

Ideas found in [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36735) serve as inspiration.

#### Download

- [Userscripts Page](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/102055)
- [Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/102055.user.js)
- [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/102055)

#### Platform

Written for and tested on Firefox 4.0 on Windows 7.  I will be trying to maintain compatibility with Chrome in future releases.  Specifically on Chrome 11.0 on Windows XP.  Hopefully combinations of either browser and OS will still work.

### Contact

Please use this page as means of contact.  This is part of a personal learning exercise using Javascript so support will be limited as I have no practical experience with it.  Feedback and improvement suggestions would be appreciated.

### Future

This will be part of a larger project which is a collection of scripts to enhance Stack Exchange if and when I figure out how to do it.

Comment: Updated: Removed dependencies on JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use this answer to keep track of progress such as bugs and plans.  That way it will be able to keep everyone up to date on the progress.

#### Acknowledged Bugs

- <s>Does not work on other browsers like Chrome</s> *(fixed)*

#### Future Plans

- **Add link to temporarily unhide ignored questions**
  *instead of toggling, I originally wanted to unhide the hidden questions.  This will hopefully be choosable via a menu.*
- **Add logic to incorporate interesting tagged questions**
  *to prevent questions that are both interesting and ignored from being hidden*